# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywhatkit' Cannot import pywhatkit on VS Code

Tags: python, automation, importerror, whatsapp, sendmessage

1. pywhatkit has been successfully installed
2. Im using python 3.10.1
3. Im using VS Code

**I've been trying to run this code:**

```
import pywhatkit
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+60123456789", "Hello from Python", 18, 20)
print("Successfully Sent!")
```

**But it keeps showing this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ben_l\.vscode\Projects and 
Application\Python\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pywhatkit
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywhatkit'
```

[pywhatkit is installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgIeI.png)

**May I know how could I fix this error?**

Comment: Can you check with `pip list` if pywhatkit is really installed in the environment that you have currently activated?

Comment: @elyptikus Yes, it is installed. Is it configuration problem with my IDLE? Im using VS Code

Answer (score 0):

If pywhatkit is in your pip list but still "flask is not in your module" error shows then install "pip install Flask" then your pywhatkit will work smoothly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31283024)